# Generic types in a Swift protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift-protocols

I need to build a UITableView with two types of cells. I'm using the Delegate pattern to update some values in these cells and to use them in a UIViewController. I need to get an Int from a cell and a Date from the other cell.

I'm pretty new to generics in Swift. I was wondering if there is a way to write a single protocol that can be used from different tableview cells to pass a value of any type.

I wrote this:

```
protocol DebugValueDelegate {
    func valueDidChange<GenericType>(_ value: GenericType, cellType: UITableViewCell.Type)
}
```

As far as I know, I can declare my generic type inside <>. I'm passing also the tableview cell type from which I'm calling the method. I'm having problems with the implementation of the method. In particular I'm not able to use a switch case to differentiate the UITableViewCell.Type. Then in each case I'd like to use the GenericType as a Date, or Int or the type I need. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

```
func valueDidChange<GenericType>(_ value: GenericType, cellType: UITableViewCell.Type) {
    switch cellType {
    case DateTableViewCell:
        if let date = value as? Date {
           //
        }
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the point of generics? Why do you think you should use generics here?

Comment: Because I want to use only one protocol for every table view cell I need, pass every type of value I want (GenericType in this case), but at the same time I want to know which cell is sending me the value. In this way I can understand the real type of GenericType. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You are not supposed to "understand the real type of `GenericType`". How about having one protocol method for each type of value or each type of table cell?

Comment: if you want to use generic on protocol you have to use associatedType this work like generics.

Comment: @Sweeper this has been my first attempt, then I wanted to improve it to have only one protocol method. Why am I not supposed to understand the real type? I need to store the value I'm getting from the cells.

Comment: @cristian_064 I have also tried what you are describing but I'm getting this error: "Protocol 'DebugValueDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"

Comment: I think what you need to use is an `associatedType`, rather than a generic.  In your case, you want the `associatedType` to conform to `Equatable.` so you can test for changes in its value.  You use the `associatedType` like an ordinary type.  In your protocol: `associatedType ChangableValue: Equatable`, then `func viewDidChange(_ value: ChangableType, cellType: UIViewCellType.Type)`

Comment: @ChipJarred A protocol with an associatedType _is_ a generic.

Comment: @matt, yes and no... in some sense, all protocols, whether they have associatedTypes or not. are generic.  Anyway, what I was trying to convey was using an associated type rather than an *explicit* generic, if splitting hairs is somehow more helpful to OP

Comment: @ChipJarred Not yes and no. Yes and yes. It's not splitting hairs at all. Adding an associated type is how you turn a protocol into a generic protocol (parameterized on the associated type).

Comment: @ChipJarred I don’t understand why I should use an associated type. And why the Equatable? After this, should I cast the associated type to the type I need, right?

Comment: @matt... Mo.  A protocol does not create a generic.  The type conforming to the protocol is a generic.   If you want to spit hairs, at least get them right.  You can create protocols with associated types all you like, but that does not create a generic... until you create a type conforming to it.  They describe constraints, properties and methods that generic types conforming to them must have.   But none of those distinctions are important to helping the OP.

Comment: @MiaSdev, having re-read your question, it's possible I'm missing context.  Do you intend for an instance conforming to`DebugValueDelegate` to be used multiple cell value types, or just one?   Originally my thinking was just for one type per instance, in which case having the`DebugValueDelegate` parameterized on that type would be helpful.  But if you need intend to pass multiple types to the same instance, then your generic may be the right way after all.  Declaring that it (or the generic parameter type) conforms to `Equatable` is just  for detecting whether two things are equal (or not).

Comment: @MiaSdev I may write an answer describing both later, if I have time.  My apartment building burned down last week, and I'm trying to salvage what I can as the fire marshal allows it.  Time at my computer is not as plentiful as it usually is.

Answer (score 0):

Protocols do not allow generic parameters,  use associated types instead.

Anyway I would suggest you do it another way- the way of type casting, when you can use just one protocol for both of your `UITableViewCells` . Code below:

```
class Cell1: UITableViewCell,DebugValueDelegate {

    func valueDidChange(_ value: Any) {       
        if let value = value as? Date {
            // here is your value as Date
        }
        if let value = value as? Int {
            // here is your value as Int
        }
    }
}

protocol DebugValueDelegate {
    func valueDidChange(_ value: Any)
}
```

Comment: This is what I did in the end, except for the second parameter. I think that passing only the UITableViewCell type is better. But I’m still wondering if there is a cleaner way…

Comment: Well , I think the purpose of clean code is to make it as simple and understandable as possible. Writing the code the shortest way can sometimes be the byproduct, but  not the goal. In my opinion generics and associated types are not necessary here and would only decrease the simplicity and readability.

Comment: Actually, if you're OK with individually testing for each type at runtime,, then yeah, `Any` or `AnyObject` with a cast will do the job.  And that might necessary if code passing the value to the delegate doesn't have any type information for the value, which would be required for generics/associatedTypes.

Comment: @MiaSdev I edited the code a bit to make it shorter..